# jQuery strip classes and style from multiple elements

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
<div id="temp">
  <p class="one two">text</p>
  <div class="two">text</div>
  <a class="three" style="color:#ccc">Text</a>

  <p class="one">text</p>
  <div class="two">text</div>
  <a class="three" style="color:#ccc">Text</a>
</div>
```

So basically, I need to scan "temp" element and remove certain classes from each child element.

I tried something like:

```
$('#temp *[class="one two"]').removeAttr('class');
```

But its not working for me.

Comment: What class you need to remove? You're removing the class attribute on your example code... what is certainly a bad idea :)

Comment: I dont want to remove elements, just to strip some of the classes

Comment: why you just dont remove the classes by removeClass like:
$("#temp").children().each(function() { $(this).removeClass("one").removeClass("two"); }); This way you could keep if there are other classes to the elements and remove only the classes you need to remove

Comment: I was thinking of that but my html code is bit more complex it goes down to 4 nested levels, which means I have to go 4 loops down. I was hoping for a simpler way.

Comment: I don't want to remove an element just defined multiple classes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need to take on both `.one` and `.two` separately in order to eradicate them completely.

```
  $('#temp .one').removeAttr('class');
  $('#temp .two').removeAttr('class');
```

There's three buttons in this Snippet:

1. Uses `$('#temp .one.two')` selector
2. Uses `$('#temp .one')` and `$('#temp .two')` selectors
3. Tests to see if anything is left over.

After clicking button #1 or #2, click #3. After seeing the results in the console, reset the Snippet before continuing on to another test.

#### SNIPPET

```js
$('#btn1').on('click', function() {
  $('#temp .one.two').removeAttr('class');
});

$('#btn2').on('click', function() {
  $('#temp .one').removeAttr('class');
  $('#temp .two').removeAttr('class');
});

$('#btn3').on('click', function() {
  console.log($('.two').length);
  console.log($('.one').length);
});
```

```css
.one { border: 2px dashed red; }
.two { background: red; }
.three { border: 2px dotted black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="temp">
  <p class="one two">text</p>
  <div class="two">text</div>
  <a class="three" style="color:#ccc">Text</a>

  <p class="one">text</p>
  <div class="two">text</div>
  <a class="three" style="color:#ccc">Text</a>
</div>
<button id='btn1'>('#temp .one.two')</button>
<button id='btn2'>('#temp .one')('#temp .two')</button>
<button id='btn3'>Check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`[class="one two"]` will match those with class which match exactly with phrase `one two` (and not `two one`, `one  two`, `one something two`,...):

```
$('#temp .one.two').removeAttr('class');
```